# Is there any problem or consideration for creating 1000 SQLite databases on a PHP server?

Tags: php, android, sqlite

In an Android application,
Users have their own stores and I want to create a separate SQLite database on one PHP server for them

Is there any problem or consideration for creating you say 1000 SQLite databases on a PHP server?

Comment: This is hard to answer without more context, but personally I would create a proper database architecture instead of giving all users their own database. SQLite is a relational dbms, so you can probably do what you want with some relationships between tables.

Comment: FYI, Each database in my design is completely separate from others and can be opened and manipulated independently, In fact I decided to use SQLite database on the server instead of JSON files there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a lot of databases on a php server shouldn't be the problem. Even having one thousand databases open is more a matter of your server resources (ram/cpu) than a php limitation. You should think about a design to limit the number of users who can have an active open database connection, otherwise you are in danger that somebody can kill your server with a 3 line script.

Comment: Can you explain more? because In my design any user can have an active open database connection

Comment: Not sure if your implementation has a counter on active users, Otherwise you need to check and count the active user connections on logon. Just increment a counter will not work, as users might just close the browser.

Comment: The Android users connect to their own databases and download or upload data from or to the database, they need to be connected whenever they want to get data for their stores or update some data to the database, is there any problem

Comment: In that case I would implement a timer to close inactive connections after a while